# Display Methods - Multiple Form Data Sources

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, x++, axapta

This may seem a simple question, but for some reason I am vexed.

I have a form with 3 datasources - `InventTable`, `InventSum`, `InventDim`.

So, for example, my grid shows;

*Item, Name, Site, Warehouse, Physical Stock*

I have placed a display method on `InventDim` form DataSource, but I need access to the `ItemId` from either `inventTrans` or `InventSum`. (Obviously looking for the "current" itemId).

All I can access is the `inventDim` which is passed as a parameter `_inventDim`, as standard.

What is the best way to access the "current" itemId?

Comment: Can I use the cursor() method?

Comment: I cannot use the cursor method - close, but not okay

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer, with great thanks to this reference by Joris de Gruyter;

http://daxmusings.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/forum-advanced-display-method-querying.html

The key was to put the display method on the `InventSum` datasource.

You can then use `_inventSum.joinChild()` to retrieve the linked `inventDim`, here is Joris' example;

```
display Qty AvailPhysical(InventSum _inventSum)
{
    InventDim       joinDim, dimValues;
    InventDimParm   dimParm;
    InventSum       localSum;

    //THE IMPORTANT LINE...
    dimValues.data(_inventSum.joinChild());

    dimParm.initFromInventDim(dimValues);

    select sum(AvailPhysical) from localSum where localSum.ItemId == _inventSum.ItemId
        #InventDimExistsJoin(localSum.InventDimId, joinDim, dimValues, dimParm);

    return localSum.AvailPhysical;
}
```

I am sure this will help someone out in the future!